# What's the best way to backup files?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, 13.10

I have a lot of personal files, which I'd like to backup, however I don't want to just copy & paste all the time from one drive to another.

Is there a better way of doing this? I have been told that raid 5 is my best bet, is this true or are there better solutions?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

for my backup I use [luckybackup](http://luckybackup.sourceforge.net/) software. It is very handily and gives you the possibility to copy and paste the command so if you want you can write your own script.
You have a lot of options:

- sync the source inside the destination
- sync source and destination
- scheduled backups
- avoid some folder inside your source
- ...and more

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Raid 5 is data protection on block level there is completely no difference for you on which RAID you are sitting if you looking for backup solution.

If you talking about Personal Documents and not scarred of using cloud data sync folders (like dropbox, google drive or Ubuntu One) I'd say you can put Dropbox onto your workstation and link it with you, lets say Documentsse one of mentioned software folder. And you will have permanent Documents folder that can be mapped to any of your workstations that have access to Internet.

There is description in here 
[Dropbox Instead of Documents](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16058/dropbox-instead-of-the-documents-folder)

Or. If you have concerns with Online data storing you can choose one from this list:
[Backup software](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/backup-ubuntu-desktop/)